# Rearrange Data frame to have subcolumns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

hey I am trying to rearrange a dataframe into one line with columns and subcolumns but i am having some trouble doing it.

I have input statistics code that looks like this :

```
                          Characteristic     Total     Male   Female
0         Total population by age groups  105145.0  50080.0  55060.0
1                           0 to 4 years    5660.0   2975.0   2685.0
2                           5 to 9 years    4105.0   2055.0   2050.0
3                         10 to 14 years    4025.0   1980.0   2040.0
4                         15 to 19 years    5105.0   2555.0   2545.0
5                               15 years     925.0    455.0    470.0
```

but I want to rearrange to be more like

```
   Total population by age groups                0 to 4 years                5 to 9 years                10 to 14 years                15 to 19 years                   15 years                                    
                            Total Male Female           Total Male Female           Total Male Female             Total Male Female             Total Male Female          Total Male Female   
0                             105145.0  50080.0    55060.0             5660.0  2975.0    2685.0             4105.0  2055.0   2050.0                4025.0   1980.0   2040.0               5105.0   2555.0   2545.0            925.0    455.0    470.0
```

i have some code but im super inexperienced with Pandas and how to use them.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Honestly not sure if thats the best way, but you can use a combination of pivot and then reindex your df.

```
df["key"] = 0  # create a common key
characteristics = df["Characteristic"].to_list()  # save original order of Characteristic

(df.pivot(index="key", columns="Characteristic")  # pivot (create one row from your data)
 .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)  # swap index levels (Characteristic in first row/level)
 .reindex(characteristics, axis=1, level=0))  # Bring index in correct order
```